# Failed to import package with error: Couldn't decompress package. UnityEditor.AssetDatabase:ImportPackage (string,bool)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, package, console

When I import tags and layers this error (below one) pops up:

```
Failed to import package with error: Couldn't decompress package
UnityEditor.AssetDatabase:ImportPackage (string,bool)
RCC_WelcomeWindow:WelcomePageContent () (at Assets/RCC/Editor/RCC_WelcomeWindow.cs:133)
RCC_WelcomeWindow:DrawToolBar () (at Assets/RCC/Editor/RCC_WelcomeWindow.cs:390)
RCC_WelcomeWindow:OnGUI () (at Assets/RCC/Editor/RCC_WelcomeWindow.cs:100)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Help if you could, thanks!

Comment: Your pack is probably corrupt. There used to a workaround, don't know if it still works. Unzip your pack using 7-zip and repack it before importing again.

Comment: Probably the package is corrupted. Else check if you have enough space on your disk, if the problem presist try unitypackage extractor get it from Github (Cobertos/unitypackage_extractor)

Comment: what exactly is `RCC_WelcomeWindow` doing?